# Find a connected graph that has exactly $2$ cutpoints of order $2$ and $3$ cutpoints of order $3$

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, connectedness, geometric-topology

> Find a connected graph that has exactly $2$ cutpoints of order $2$ and $2$ cutpoints of order $3$

**Definition:** A cut point of order $k$ is a point $a \in X$ whose complement $X-\{a\}$ consists of $k$ path-connected components.

Let the yellow dots be the cutpoints of order $2$ and the red ones of order $3$. How can I connect them to achieve the right graph?

I know that connectedness and path-connectedness are equivalent for graphs.

[image: vertices]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to add some extra vertices:

[image]

Comment: ah yes.. the question did not specify that the cutpoints were the only points. thanks - that looks right. was this done pretty much by trial and error?

Comment: yeah, pretty much :)